# Errors when following Android tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following android tutorials from mybringback site. I've followed correctly but I've got an error and I don't understand why:

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {

    MapView map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

logCat:

> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): Process:
>   com.prashant.maps, PID: 1483
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.prashant.maps/com.prashant.maps.Main}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class com.google.android.maps.Mapview
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class com.google.android.maps.Mapview
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   com.prashant.maps.Main.onCreate(Main.java:15)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   ... 10 more
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.maps.Mapview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.prashant.maps-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   ... 20 more
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.Mapview
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):       at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):       at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):       at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):       at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):       ... 23 more
>
> 02-24 14:58:12.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack available

Comment: It can't find MapView.  Did you include the Google Play Services library in your app?  If using Eclipse did you set the API level to be the Google Play version, not the AOSP version?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to not have reference to the com.google.android.maps library. Check if it is included into solution (in Build Path, Order and Export tab, there should be checked this library) or you can include into project as open source

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either in the xml file or you have not included the GoogleplayServices in your project. Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) tutorial to integrate GooglePlayServices in your project. Also, it seems you are using the earlier version of GoogleMaps for Android which is deprecated now. Follow tutorial on Google Developers page. Its not as tough as it seems. Atleast give it a try. You can find the link [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html)